# WordPress website get offline, Using Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean

I have developed a website http://kbcgbjjtodayquestion.com/ where we share the latest news about KBC 2018. The website uses WordPress CMS and is hosted on Digital Ocean using DO Droplet with the layer for 5$/mo.

I am facing a problem as the website gets often offline. Within 1 week I have hosted this site 5 times, but every time it gets offline due to some unknown reason.

I contact Technical Department of Digital Ocean, they send mail as follow.

Email from Digital Ocean: "We've detected an outgoing Denial of Service attack (http://do.co/21Y1Gc1) originating from your Droplet. Specifically, we have detected inbound traffic exceeding 0.07 Mb/s and outbound traffic exceeding 884.07 Mb/s. Due to the traffic’s harmful nature, your Droplet was taken offline; this means it is not connected to the internet and all hosted sites and services are unreachable. We know that this action is disruptive, but it’s necessary to protect you, our network, and the target of your Droplet’s attack."

**What should I do now, should I change my current Host provider?** 
Could you also please give any suggestion on other reliable hosting providers?

Answer (score 0):

If your website is sending some phishing requests, then digital ocean will definitely put your droplet down. Even me too faced this problem, then I have changed my hosting to GoDaddy.

Please contact the hosting provider before migrating.